# Select query to exclude group by column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can i select all records where all code value is not 651, 652, 655, 656 for an unique ID.

Source table with 3 columns

```
ID Line Code
1 1 651
1 2 652
1 3 655
2 1 650
2 2 652
3 1 651
3 2 655
3 3 651
3 4 658
4 1 651
4 2 651
```

I want to retrieve all records where not all code is one of 651/652/655/656 for an ID

Resultant data set would be like below

```
ID Line Code 
2 1 650 
2 2 652 
3 1 651 
3 2 655 
3 3 651 
3 4 658
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT 651 AS code UNION SELECT 652 UNION 
    SELECT 655 UNION SELECT 656
  ) AS t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
  WHERE t2.code is NULL
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba75fe/16)
*(demo for mysql but still the same for sql server 2005)

```
| ID | Line | Code |
|----|------|------|
|  2 |    1 |  650 |
|  2 |    2 |  652 |
|  3 |    1 |  651 |
|  3 |    2 |  655 |
|  3 |    3 |  651 |
|  3 |    4 |  658 |
```

Comment: conditional aggregation in a subquery would be another option

Comment: Well, for any future viewers.. This is insanely more complex than it needs to be, mainly because of the misleading notion that `IN()` wasn't available in SQL Server 2005 that is going around in this question.

Comment: @AaronDietz In the first version I solved it with in, but for the first comment I changed it to this way without in, but you are correct, in exists in 2005 normally as well as exists. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @StephenParker Yeah I saw it happen, and I only blame the docs for the confusion.  In a few years SQL Server 2005 will have been released before new developers were even born.. I wonder how many of them will get stuck working with it and be extremely confused due to the doc wording...

Comment: @AaronDietz - They do have a separate docs for 2005 see this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @StephenParker That makes me feel somewhat better, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You would check where there exists a Code not in those values for the lineitem.
This can be done via subquery. For example:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID int, Line int, Code int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 (1, 1, 651),(1, 2, 652),(1, 3, 655),(2, 1, 650),(2, 2, 652),(3, 1, 651)
 ,(3, 2, 655),(3, 3, 651),(3, 4, 658),(4, 1, 651),(4, 2, 651)

SELECT ID, Line, Code 
  FROM @temp T1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM @temp T2
                WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
                  AND T2.Code NOT IN (651, 652, 655, 656)
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method without using IN or Exists.  It utilizes conditional aggregation in a sub query to determine if more records than the unwanted Codes exists per ID and then joins back to the original table to get further details.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ID int, Line INT, Code INT)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID, Line, Code)
VALUES (1, 1, 651),(1, 2, 652),(1, 3, 655),(2, 1, 650),(2, 2, 652)
       ,(3, 1, 651),(3, 2, 655),(3, 3, 651),(3, 4, 658),(4, 1, 651)
       ,(4, 2, 651)

SELECT t1.*
FROM
    @Table t1
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          ID
       FROM
          @Table
       GROUP BY
          ID
       HAVING
          COUNT(*) > COUNT(CASE WHEN Code = 651 OR Code = 652 OR Code = 655 OR Code = 656 THEN Code END)) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```